# STM32F407VGT6Z UART Communication - No data appearing in serial terminal

Tags: c, stm32, uart

I am trying to send the string "Text " to my console on the PC to which my STM board is connected. Listed below is the configuration for the console:

[CONSOLE CONFIGURATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQvTp.png)

Nothing actually appears in the console when the board is connected and the console is open. I have placed a flashing green light before and after the transmit function to ensure that it is actually executing. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code in the main.c file.

```
#include "main.h"

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);

int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();

  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GREEN_LED_GPIO_Port, GREEN_LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      HAL_Delay(500);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)"TEST ", 6, 50);
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GREEN_LED_GPIO_Port, GREEN_LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      HAL_Delay(500);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GREEN_LED_GPIO_Port, GREEN_LED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : GREEN_LED_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GREEN_LED_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GREEN_LED_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
      
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Comment: This really depends on the board you are using, if the board includes an IC that takes UART from your STM32F4 MCU and converts it to a USB COM port on your computer, then what you have should work (assuming that you are using correct pins).

Comment: @MathiasE The board I am using is an STM32f4-discovery board. Do I need some type of converter from HUART to USB. The current set up is a mini USB plugged directly into the board and into the PC I am trying to communicate with.

Comment: "*The current set up is a mini USB plugged directly into the board and into the PC*" -- That is not the connection for a UART of the STM32F407VGT6 MCU.  You need to study the board's documentation.  "*Do I need some type of converter from HUART to USB.*" -- There is no hardware device called "*HUART*"; that's an STM software construct.  But yes, you are going to need a converter.